# Linux Dependency Errors (can't install Stella)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sdl, apt-get, dpkg

I'm trying to install the Stella Atari Emulator on Ubuntu 20.04 for a course that I'm taking.

I get the following error:

```
sudo dpkg -i stella_6.5.3_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package stella.
(Reading database ... 202707 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack stella_6.5.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking stella (6.5.3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of stella:
 stella depends on libsdl2-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.14); however:
  Version of libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 on system is 2.0.10+dfsg1-3.

dpkg: error processing package stella (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 stella
```

I have been trying to figure out a way to install the specific version of libsdl2 required for this installation, but I can't figure out how to get the 2.0.14 version. Any suggestions?

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0=2.0.14
```

And similar commands with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stella` version you downloaded is not compatible with the official `libsdl2` packet versions of your Ubuntu version. If you just want to use `stella`, it is available to install as a compatible version through `apt`:

```
apt install stella
```

Comment: You just saved me a big headache. Thank you.